# Append data to Excel column using VB6 ADO

Tags: excel, vb6, adodb

I am testing a sample VB6 application which inserts text from TextBox to Excel.
I would like to find the last used row in the column, and append text from `txt1` TextBox at the next row whenever user clicks a button.
The range is from `C10` to `C49`.
After the last row is filled, I will prompt user to open new Excel file.

I am unable to do the appending part. Below is the code I tried:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
  Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim szConnect As String

  szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Excel\Format.xls;" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO';"

  objConn.Open szConnect

  Dim xrow As Integer
  Dim lastRow As Integer
  lastRow = 10
  xrow = 49
  Do while lastRow <= xrow
    objConn.Execute "UPDATE [Sheet1$C" & lastRow & ":C" & lastRow & "] SET F1 =" &      txt1.Text & ";"
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
  Loop 
End Sub
```

The code fills the whole range on each update. I know where my mistake is, but can't figure out proper way. How to make it insert only once until row `49`?

Using Excel Object model is not an option as I want to be able to make updates when workbook is open in Excel.

Comment: Are you sure you desperately want to use ADO? Getting last used cell in a column would be a breeze using Excel Object Model. Something along the lines of `Range("C1").End(xldown).Select`.

Comment: Yes.Because the excel file need to be open while updating the cells.
I tried use Excel Object before, but it won't let me update when the file is opened.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve this would be to declare your `lastRow` as more visible (e.g. as private member of your form class), drop looping, and increment `lastRow` only once per update:

```
Private lastRow As Integer
'...
objConn.Execute _
    "UPDATE [Sheet1$C" & lastRow & ":C" & lastRow _
    & "] SET F1 =" & txt1.Text & ";"
lastRow = lastRow + 1
```

If you assume no complete control over the target Excel range (e.g. data in the range may be modified between your updates, and you do not wish to overwrite those changes) then you could search for the first empty cell before every update. Use `IsNull()` to test for empty cells.

```
Private Const RANGE_IS_FULL     As Long = -1

' Returns first vacant position in sRange Excel range (zero-based)
' Returns RANGE_IS_FULL if no vacant position was found
' sConnectionString: connection string to Excel workbook
' sRange: Excel range of a form [Sheet1$C10:C49]
Private Function GetNextAppendPosition(sConnectionString As String _
    , sRange As String) As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset

    Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    oRS.CursorLocation = ADODB.adUseClient

    oRS.Open "SELECT F1 FROM " & sRange _
        , sConnectionString

    oRS.MoveFirst
    GetNextAppendPosition = RANGE_IS_FULL
    lRow = -1
    While Not oRS.EOF
        lRow = lRow + 1
        If IsNull(oRS.Fields(0).Value) Then
            GetNextAppendPosition = lRow
            GoTo hExit
        End If
        oRS.MoveNext
    Wend

hExit:
    oRS.Close
End Function
```

With this in mind, your update routine could be coded as this:

```
Public Sub ExportTextToExcelRow(sText As String)
    Const CONNECTION_STRING As String = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\src\Excel ADO\Book1.xls;" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO';    "
    Const MAX_TARGET_ROW    As Long = 49
    Const MIN_TARGET_ROW    As Long = 10
    Const TARGET_COL        As String = "C"
    Const TARGET_SHEET      As String = "Sheet1"

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim sTargetRange As String

    sTargetRange = "[" & TARGET_SHEET & "$" & TARGET_COL & MIN_TARGET_ROW _
        & ":" & TARGET_COL & MAX_TARGET_ROW & "]"
    lRow = GetNextAppendPosition(CONNECTION_STRING, sTargetRange)
    If lRow = RANGE_IS_FULL Then
        MsgBox "Oops, range is full."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    lRow = lRow + MIN_TARGET_ROW

    sTargetRange = "[" & TARGET_SHEET & "$" & TARGET_COL & lRow _
        & ":" & TARGET_COL & lRow & "]"

    oConn.Open CONNECTION_STRING
    oConn.Execute "UPDATE " & sTargetRange & " SET F1 = """ & sText & """;"
    oConn.Close
End Sub
```

Call it from your event handler this way:

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
    ExportTextToExcelRow txt1.Text
End Sub
```